# Collecting logs from different remote servers using just Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

Is it possible to send logs from different remote machines to elasticsearch using just logstash(no filebeats)? Is so, do I define same index in all the conf.d file in all the machines? I want all the logs to be in the same index.

Would i use `logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}` for the index of all config files to have them indexed into the same folder?

```
input {
  file {
    part => /home/ubuntu/logs/data.log
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index =>"logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be possible are you going to install Logstash on all remote instances ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is ok and it will work. Just one thing I would correct is that you should simply write to a [data stream](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-data-streams) and not have to care about the index name and ILM matters (rollover, retention, etc), like this:

```
input {
  file {
    part => /home/ubuntu/logs/data.log
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    data_stream => "true"
    data_stream_type => "logs"
    data_stream_dataset => "ubuntu"
    data_stream_namespace => "prod"
  }
}
```

The data stream name will be `logs-ubuntu-prod`, you can change the latter two to your liking.

Make sure to properly set up your [data stream](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-streams.html) first, with an adequate [Index Lifecycle Management policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html), though.

On a different note, it's a waste of resource to install Logstash on all your remote machines which is supposed to work as [centralized streaming engine](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/deploying-and-scaling.html#_beats_and_logstash). You should definitely either use Filebeat, or even better now the [Elastic Agent](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/index.html) which is fully manageable through Fleet in Kibana. You should have a look.